# I'm trying integerate facebook login it shows "view controller does not conform protocol"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

here's the code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() 

{ 
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        print("Not logged in..")
    }
    else
    {

        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self //shows error:view controller does not conform to protocol 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'

    }
   super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

And the loginButton method

```
 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    if error == nil
    {
        print("Login complete.")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNew", sender: self)
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
{
    print("User logged out...")
}
```

[image]

The view controller is frontpageViewConroller,I have logged into facebook registered with the AppId downloaded the iOS SDK and imported them,unable to solve this help me out

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you setting the delegate on you viewController like following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
```

Please check the following full tutorial login with Facebook for swift

[Tutorial: How To Use Login in Facebook SDK 4.1.x for Swift](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)